# C++11 translation phase 8 confusion

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, c++11

> Phase 7: White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant.
>   Each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting
>   tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a
>   translation unit.
>
> Phase 8: Translated translation units and instantiation units are combined
>   as follows:  Each translated translation unit is examined to produce a
>   list of required instantiations. The definitions of the required
>   templates are located. It is implementation-defined whether the source
>   of the translation units containing these definitions is required to
>   be available.  All the required instantiations are performed to
>   produce instantiation units.[ Note: These are similar to translated
>   translation units, but contain no references to uninstantiated
>   templates and no template definitions. —end note ] The program is
>   ill-formed if any instantiation fails.

I have removed some of the notes to shorten the pasted text.

Why are templates locating and instantiating performed after the translation unit has already been translated in C++'s compilation phase 8? Shouldn't these steps take place in phase 7 considering the two-phase name look-up?

Comment: Reading the question over and over I somewhat have the feeling you have a misunderstanding what the "Q&A site for programming questions" actually means. You don't leave blocks of "your own understanding questions" because of "learning programming" here and then expect an answer.

Comment: I will try to clarify hakre's comment: In almost all cases it is better for one SO question to contain only one programming question, like "Why is there a template-definition location step in C++'s compilation phase 8?" with a question text excerpting the standard, and mentioning phase 7 two-phase look-up. This alone would be one question. Stuffing too much into a single question will reduce the question's value for SO, and also reduce the amount of answers you will get.  Also, please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying hakre's comment gimpf, hope it's better this time, altough it seems to me like you understood the questions. When I try to explain something to someone I tend to divide what he doesn't understand and treat the parts sequentially; I feel that is better and more efficient this way so that's why I opted for the initial layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a holdover from the [now-deprecated](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3065.html) *export templates* feature.  Export templates allowed the definition of class and function templates to be located separately from their declaration (in an appropriate sense).

As an implementation detail, separating translation unit translation from template instantiation can make sense, as it can reduce redundant work instantiating templates.  However, most current compilers instantiate all templates at translation unit translation and eliminate duplicate instantiations at link time.

It is hoped that concepts and modules will allow a similar feature to be reintroduced to the language in future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this portion has to do with the pre-compilation of templated types. Any type that is templated would be an "instantiation unit". If the templated type is in a pre-compiled then it would need to be handled in this phase.